# Export of large amounts of data with JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

If i try to export large amounts of data with `JMSSerializerBundle` i get the following error.

> FatalErrorException: Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes
>   exhausted (tried to allocate 1332351 bytes) in
>   /var/www/app/trunk/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/DataCollector.php
>   line 27

If i export only few records with this bundle, everything works fine.

```
$format = 'json';
$serializer = \JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$serializer->serialize($data, $format, SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
```

The count of array `$data` is `1917`

How can i handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do somewhere in your script a:

```
echo ini_get('memory_limit'); // To see how much memory you have
```

And then update the memory_limit settings in the php.ini file. Restart the server and try it again.

Comment: Current i have 128M, i increase the memory_limit in the function, where i need it to 256M "ini_set('memory_limit', '256M')". If i modify my "php.ini" and restart php "/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart", my modification take no effect on the app. Is it better to set this in the ini file?

Comment: It depends if you want to have it local for all your stuff or just there. Do you see a different output for echo ini_get('memory_limit') or not ?  If not, try to set it in the ini (Double check that is the apache ini and not the cli ini)

Comment: It's the correct ini. If i call "phpinfo()" the path of my pnp ini file is "/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini". I modify the "memory_limit" and restart "php5-fpm" and "apache", but nothing happen. The "memory_limit" is not modify if i call "phpinfo()". I do not know how can i solve this. Is 256M ok for a php app, or should i increase this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have found nothing. I set this part in the function, but that is not programmed clean, a temporary solution :)